# ¿Como agregar un convertidor(GSON) a retrofit en netbeans para proyecto javaFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, retrofit, gson

Como ya lo leyeron arriba, estoy tratando de configurar un **convertidor** a `retrofit` , todo esto en netbeans ,  para android ya lo se  usar y ahí lo agrege con Gradle y en netbeans con `maven` pero a la hora de hacer la clase donde configuro `retrofit` y voy agregar `GSON` como convertidor, netbeans no me reconoce la instrucción aunque agregue el `import`:

```
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje

> package retrofit2.converter.gson does not exist

Se supone que tiene que existir pues uso la misma version de `retrofit` que he usado en android la **2.3.0**

Este es mi codigo

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory; //marca el error


/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class ConfigRetrofit {

    private static final String url = "mi url";

    private static final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();


     private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   ;
```

y de lado de mi api con la que estoy tratando de conectar esta todo bien , lo que no me  permite avanzar es esto, ojola alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias

Comment: Ya resolviste el problema??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da ese error porque la libreria que usa el converter no existe en esa libreria esta en `com.squareup.retrofit2` la puedes descargar jar en este [link](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.squareup.retrofit2&a=converter-gson&v=LATEST)

- Puedes agregarlo con `maven` de esta manera:

  ```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
  <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
  <version>latest.version</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Con `gradle` puedes agregarlo de esta manera:

  ```
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:latest.version'
  ```

Comment: `<dependencies>        
        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
                <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
            
    </dependencies>`

De echo lo tengo así en maven pero no funciona a pesar de que si importa la librería y no funciona

Comment: Revisa si esta descargando cuando le das compilas con dependencias

Comment: Si aparece de la forma que  ya tenia configurado el pom.xml, y con la forma que tu me dijiste cuando trato de compilar   me aparece un error , pero en dependencias si me aparece el .jar

Comment: Que error te esta mostrando?

Comment: creo que ya se pudo , solo me falto modificar la parte que dice lastest.version a 2.4.0, ya que  yo le ponia 2.8.0 ya que ese numero de version es el que tiene el jar  que se decargo de los repositorios de google pero la version de los repositorios de retrofit es la 2.4.0  , ya no me marco error y ya compilo y hasta ahorita todo bien, ¿Crees que haya problema en usar el .jar  de los repositorios de  retrofit en lugar de la de  google?

Comment: No deberian de ser los mismos prueba  y me cuentas si necesitas ayuda

Comment: esto soluciona mi pregunta , aun falta mas por hacer  pero con lo que me ayudaste ya pude solucionar el problema , muchas gracias.... saludos